# How to pass values from a usercontrol to a customcontrol using style in Generic.xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, custom-controls

In trying to make a simple customcontrol that accepts a string (Text), I am having difficulty passing values from the XAML to the customcontrol by way of the style in Generic.xaml.

The calling XAML does:

```
<wc:ccTestFigure Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

The ccTestFigure is defined as:

```
 public class ccTestFigure : FrameworkElement
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        TextBlock.TextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(ccTestFigure));

    public String Text
    {
        get { return (String)this.GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    static ccTestFigure()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ccTestFigure), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ccTestFigure)));
    }

    public ccTestFigure()
    {

        var typeface = new Typeface(
                        FontFamily,
                        FontStyle,
                        FontWeights.Normal,
                        FontStretches.Normal);

       ft  = new FormattedText(
               Text,
               System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
               FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
               typeface,
               FontSize,
               Foreground);
    }


  protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        drawingContext.DrawText(ft, new Point());
    }
```

The Style in Generic.xaml does not like TemplateBinding, so I am at a loss how to pass the Text in from the usercontrol to the customcontrol, ccTestFigure.

The Style I have so far (which does not work) is:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ccTestFigure}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Style>
```

Where Text is a simple string.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to do something completely redundant, set the value of "Text" to itself.

The problem is just that you're not updating "ft" when "Text" changes.  Add a property-change handler, and put the formatted-text stuff in there instead of the constructor:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    TextBlock.TextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(ccTestFigure), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(propertyChangedCallback: OnTextChanged));

private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ((ccTestFigure)sender).UpdateText();
}

private void UpdateText() 
{
    var typeface = new Typeface(
                    FontFamily,
                    FontStyle,
                    FontWeights.Normal,
                    FontStretches.Normal);

   ft  = new FormattedText(
           Text,
           System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
           FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
           typeface,
           FontSize,
           Foreground);
}

public ccTestFigure()
{
}
```

Comment: @McGamagle Why is the <TextBlock> element used? Thanks.

Comment: @McGamagle...Umm..."ControlTemplate" is NOT a property of ccTestFigure. (ccTestFigure inherits from FrameworkElement).  What to do???

Comment: @AlanWayne my mistake.  It looks like the problem is just that Text gets set after the constructor has completed.  So you need to put that logic in a property change handler (see my edit).

Comment: @McGamagle Thanks. So don't use the <Style> in Generic.xaml to transfer values?

Comment: @AlanWayne right, you shouldn't need to "transfer" values.  The "Text" property gets set when you write `<wc:ccTestFigure Text="..."`.

Comment: @McGamagle When using a breakpoint, UpdateText() is never called when Text is sent to the UserControl housing the ccTextFigure??

Comment: @AlanWayne I see -- I was able to reproduce it.  I see that, instead of using `OverrideMetadata`, if I create a new dependency property "Text", then it works correctly.  I'm not sure why your version doesn't work ...

Comment: @AlanWayne ok, figured it out.  You just have to put the property-changed callback, in the override for `AddOwner`.  My updated answer should work now.

Comment: @McGamagle So drop the static constructor with OverrideMetadata??

Comment: @McGamagle Umm...Now I'm getting "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: textToFormat" at  ((ccTestFigure)sender).UpdateText(); Ideas? (Sincere thanks for your time.)

Comment: @McGamagle If it matters, I am first creating this control empty. It waits for text elsewhere on the screen to be selected and is populated by an observablecollection in the usercontrol. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67356/discussion-between-alan-wayne-and-mcgarnagle).

Answer (score 1):

I post this as I know no other way to show the code. McGamagle is correct--just needed to make a few changes as below. Needed to add "AffectsRender" to display the text.

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        TextBlock.TextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(ccTextFigure),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null,                                               
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure,    
            propertyChangedCallback: OnTextChanged              
            ));
```

In my case, I also needed AffectsMeasure to force a re-measuring for the parent scrollviewer.